# Are AWS ECS, EKS, and Fargate easily replaced with eachother?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I'm a bit new to container orchestration. I understand the differences between ECS, EKS, and Fargate from a high level, and I think they all use ECR to store containers. My question is, since they all seem to run on docker containers, do containers have to be configured in any way when switching from one container orchestration service to another?

Comment: They use completely different approaches to configuration. For any non-trivial deployment, it will require as much work to translate that configuration as it would to write it from scratch. And that assumes that you minimize the number of orchestration-dependent options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are AWS ECS, EKS, and Fargate easily replaced with each other?

ECS and EKS are container orchestration. Fargate is a container runtime environment. Basically you run your containers by telling either ECS or EKS to deploy them, and as part of that you tell them to run those containers on either Fargate or EC2 instances.

> I think they all use ECR to store containers.

ECS and EKS can pull container images from ECR, or any other image registry they have access to, like DockerHub.

> My question is, since they all seem to run on docker containers, do
> containers have to be configured in any way when switching from one
> container orchestration service to another?

You should be able to run containers without modifying them for any ECS/EKS or EC2/Fargate specific environments. For example you should be able to tell either one to pull the official Nginx image off DockerHub and run it fine without any modifications. There are some more advanced scenarios where you may need to modify your containers for ECS or EKS, but those aren't common. The more common scenario is adding sidecar containers to take advantage of extra features like AWS App Mesh.

Comment: +1 to what Mark said. More background on the role of Fargate in the big picture [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/the-role-of-aws-fargate-in-the-container-world/)